# Exporting Scrapy requests in Curl format

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

[image]

I use Postman for API testing , which has the ability to import curl commands.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/importing_curl

Can scrapy export in this format (or any other format) ? This may help in debugging requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`minreq`](https://github.com/csalazar/minreq) to ouptut a Scrapy Request from curl. It even only outputs the necessary data to send to repeat the same request successfully.

Comment: Awesome, it looks like its available through pip.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly answering the question, but I hope may help as well.

I remember going to browser developer tools, using the "Copy as cURL" functionality, then pasting it to the textbox [here](http://curl.trillworks.com/) and getting a Python+Requests code, which should be easier to transform into `Scrapy.Request()` call.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at this.

Comment: I've used the interceptor add on to postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) . This can capture requests directly from chrome.